# ISO Mussar Sefer similar to Orchos Yosher

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books

I’ve recently been learn HaGaon HaRav Chaim Kanievsky’s Sefer, Orchos Yosher. I specifically have the Artscroll English/Hebrew version and would ideally prefer something like that as my Hebrew is far from ideal.

I like how the Sefer brings different ideas from Chazal, Rishonim, and Achronim, ordered by different values in a clear way.

Does anyone have recommendations to something like that?

Comment: There are lots of Artscroll translations of several mussar seforim that bring such ideas together - is that literally what you're after?

Comment: What's ISO?....

Comment: IN SEARCH OF @ROBEV